# Синтаксический разбор сложносочиненного предложения

Tags: грамматика, синтаксический-разбор

Помогите, пожалуйста, составить схему предложения и найти основу простых предложений в составе ССП?

*Мне поручили взять палатку, а моему товарищу — спальный мешок.*

Answer (score 2):

*Мне **поручили** взять палатку, а моему товарищу — спальный мешок.*

[ =  ], а [  ].

**Сложносочиненное** предложение, сочинительный союз ***А***. Второе предложение **неполное**, пропущено: поручили взять.

Простые предложение в ССП односоставные **неопределенно-личные**, сказуемое ***поручили***. Инфинитив ***взять*** является дополнением: поручили (что?) ***взять***.